Conditions on positivity of Riemann squared products in Euclidean space?
I wonder if it is known whether there are simple conditions on $u,v$ such that:
$$R_{abcd}R^{abcd}+ u R_{ab}R^{ab} + vR^2 = A_{abcd}A^{abcd}$$
and thus proving that the combination is always positive in 4D Euclidean space for those particular values?
There seems to be enough degrees of freedom with
$$A_{abcd}= R_{abcd}+\alpha_1 g_{ab}R_{cd}+\alpha_2 g_{ac}R_{bd}+\alpha_3 g_{ad}R_{bd}+...+\alpha_7 g_{ab}g_{cd}R+..$$
(for real coefficients $\alpha_n$)
such that there should be a great many values of $u,v$ such that this is the case. But conversely it is easy shown that if $w$ is large and negative then this cannot be true. Hence my assumption is that for certain values of $u,v$ it can be written as such but not all.
In particular I wonder if the Gauss-Bonnet term can be written as such with $v=-4$ and $w=1$ (this might help.  )
